# Who do Merry men brigade refer to?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I was reading God save the mark by Donald Westlake when I came across this line:

> On the way, the operator—green uniform, possibly a passed-over captain in the **Merry Men Brigad**e—said, “You the nephew?”

I just want to know who are these merry men brigade?

Answer (score 3):

He is wearing a green uniform so is being compared, in a mocking sense, to one of
"The Merry Men" who are the group of outlaws who follow Robin Hood in English literature and folklore. The band appears in the earliest ballads about Robin Hood and remains popular in modern adaptations, film and TV. They dress in a color shade referred to as Lincoln Green.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you.